# Calculating men's risk of getting coronary heart disease

Tags: java, beginner, android

I'd like anyone here to help me clean up my code. It's about calculating men's risk of getting coronary heart disease. [Here's the link to my method](https://gist.github.com/akosijiji/57d0da84b24ea9f6dd0e).

```
private void calculateForMen(){

 // TODO
 // For Men
 // 20–34 years: Minus 9 points. 
 // 35–39 years: Minus 4 points. 
 // 40–44 years: 0 points. 
 // 45–49 years: 3 points.
 // 50–54 years: 6 points. 
 // 55–59 years: 8 points. 
 // 60–64 years: 10 points. 
 // 65–69 years: 11 points. 
 // 70–74 years: 12 points. 
 // 75–79 years: 13 points.

        // TODO Men Age 20-34
        if( strAge.equals("20 to 34") ){ // Minus 7 points

            // First point
            points = points - 9;

            // Second point
            if( strTotalCholesterol.equals("160 to 199") ){// 4 points
                points = points + 4;
            }
            else if( strTotalCholesterol.equals("200 to 239") ){ // 8 points
                points = points + 7;
            }
            else if( strTotalCholesterol.equals("240 to 279") ){ // 11 points
                points += 9;
            }
            else if( strTotalCholesterol.equals("280 or greater") ){ // 13 points
                points += 11;
            }

            // Third point
            if( strHDL.equals("60 or greater") ) // Minus 1 point
            {
                points -= 1;
            }
            else if( strHDL.equals("40 to 49") ){ // 1 point
                points += 1;
            }
            else if( strHDL.equals("Less than 40") ){ // 2 points
                points += 2;
            }

            // Fourth point
            if( strSBP.equals("130 to 139") ){ // 2 points
                points += 1;
            }
            else if( strSBP.equals("140 to 159") ){ // 3 points
                points += 1;
            }
            else if( strSBP.equals("160 or greater") ){ // 4 points
                points += 2;
            }
```

Comment: Longest single method EVER! So first thing you need to look up is how to use methods / refactor. Second your indention levels are a bit out of sync. That is first glance. I'll edit a little bit and post a answer in a second

Comment: Your repeat yourself very frequently. There are a few easy ways around this, one is to make a interface for each gender/age group. That interface will have the strings `strSBP`, `strSmoker` etc and it will have methods such as `GetSBPPoints()` `GetSmokerPoints` etc. Then in your main method you make a instantiate a new class based on the age and gender then call the methods to get the points. Once you get your points then display your message.

Comment: Another way around this is to put in a few parameters in those methods to calculate the Points so that it can do the math to adjust the returned points.

Comment: Hello can you show me how to implement those? Thanks I really need your help because I'm new to java programming.

Comment: Please paste the code into the question as per the FAQ, otherwise I'll have to close the question.

Comment: @WinstonEwert my codes are very long so I just pasted it in gist.

Comment: @neknekmouh, I don't care how long it is. You have to post it into the question. If it can't fit post a sample of it.

Comment: @WinstonEwert I posted the code as per your request...

Answer (score 3):

Each of your if blocks are very similar. You basically the same thing in each if block. This a sign that you've got the conditionally at the wrong level. Instead of writing code that does:

1. If age category 1

   1. Add points for age
   2. Add points for cholestoral
   3. etc
2. If age category 2

   1. Add points for age
   2. Add points for cholestoral
   3. etc
3. etc

Write it like this:

1. Add points for age

   1. Handle age category 1
   2. Handle age category 2
   3. etc
2. Add points for cholestoral

   1. Handle age category 1
   2. Handle age category 2
   3. etc
3. etc

So adding the age points should look something like:

```
if( strAge.equals("20 to 34") ){ // Minus 7 points
    points = points - 9;
}
else if( strAge.equals("35 to 39") ){
    points = points - 4;
}
else if( strAge.equals("35 to 39") ){
    points = points - 4;
}
else if( strAge.equals("40 to 44") ){
    points += 0;
} 
else if( strAge.equals("45 to 49") ){
    points += 3;
}
else if( strAge.equals("50 to 54") ){
    points += 6;
}
else if( strAge.equals("55 to 59") ){
    points += 8;
}
else if( strAge.equals("60 to 64") ){
    points += 10;
}
else if( strAge.equals("65 to 69") ){
    points += 11;
}
else if( strAge.equals("70 to 74") ){
    points += 12;
}
else if( strAge.equals("75 to 79") ){
    points += 13;
}
```

But doesn't that repeat the `.equals` way too much? Yes. But the repetition here is much simpler and easier to deal with then what you had before. So we prefer this. Once we have this we can simplify it.

The next key is to use data not code. That is, make lists of things and look them up rather then putting them in code.

```
static String [] ageCategories = {"20 to 34", "35 to 39", "40 to 44", "45 to 49", "50 to 54", "55 to 59", "60 to 64", "64 to 69", "70 to 74", "75 to 79"}
static int agePoints = {-9, -4, -4, 0, 3, 6, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13};

points += agePoints[Arrays.asList(ageCategories).indexOf(strAge)];
```

This looks up the age level and the points by looking in the arrays. No ifs required. You should basically not need to use any if statements whatsoever in this particular code. You should rewrite it to fetch everything out of arrays like this.

As the number of age ranges increases, it may be easier to work with a map because each point adjustment is matched up to its corresponding age range.

```
static final Map<String, Integer> pointsByAgeRange = new HashMap<>() {{
    put("20 to 34", -9);
    put("35 to 39", -4);
    ...
    put("75 to 79", 13);
}};

points += pointsByAgeRange.get(strAge);  // assumes range is in map
```

Comment: Use a `Map<String, Integer>` instead of the paired arrays.

Comment: @DavidHarkness, good thought. But I don't do Java enough to know the syntax. Is there a way to do a map literal? Feel free to edit my answer to show the better way.

Comment: Sadly, Java doesn't yet have a map literal, but the anonymous subclass trick I included comes pretty close.

Comment: Thanks!  It's a good trick to know when I'm called upon to use Java in the future.

Comment: David and Winston Map<String, Integer> is fit for this.

Comment: @neknekmouh, what?

Answer (score 1):

So I'm not going to show you what a interface is (since I am at work) but I can show you a small blurb of what i'm talking about. Note that the number I put into this are not meant to be accurate, they are just to get you started.

```
interface Patient
{
    int getAgePoints();
    int getChloresterolPoints(String chlor);
    int getHDLPoints(String hdl);
    int getSBPPoints(String sbp);
    int getSmokerPoints(String smoker);
}
class UnkownPatient implements Patient
{
    public UnkownPatient()
    {
    }
    @Override
    public int getChloresterolPoints(String chlor)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getHDLPoints(String hdl)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getSBPPoints(String sbp)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getSmokerPoints(String smoker)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getAgePoints()
    {
        return 0;
    }

}
class PatientMan20to34 implements Patient
{
    public PatientMan20to34()
    {
    }

    @Override
    public int getAgePoints()
    {
        return -9;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChloresterolPoints(String chlor)
    {
        switch (chlor)
        {
            case "160 to 199":
                return 4;
            case "200 to 239":
                return 7;
            case "240 to 279":
                return 9;
            case "280 or greater":
                return 11;
            default:
                return 0;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getHDLPoints(String hdl)
    {
        // Third point
        switch (hdl)
        {
            case "60 or greater":
                return -1;
            case "40 to 49":
                return 1;
            case "Less than 40":
                return 2;
            default:
                return 0;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getSBPPoints(String sbp)
    {
        switch (sbp)
        {
            case "130 to 139":
                return 1;
            case "140 to 159":
                return 1;
            case "160 or greater":
                return 2;
            default:
                return 0;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getSmokerPoints(String smoker)
    {
        if (smoker.equals("Yes"))
        {
            return 8;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

then to work it now you have the following

```
public CoronaryHeart()
{
    String strAge =  "20 to 34";
    String strTotalChloresterol = "240 to 279";
    String strHDL = "30 to 49";
    String strSBP = "140 to 159";
    String strIsSmoker = "No";

    Patient p = new UnkownPatient();
    switch(strAge)
    {
        case "20 to 34":
            p = new PatientMan20to34();
    }

    int points = p.getAgePoints();
    points += p.getChloresterolPoints(strTotalChloresterol);
    points += p.getHDLPoints(strHDL);
    points += p.getSBPPoints(strSBP);
    points += p.getSmokerPoints(strIsSmoker);

    DisplayAlterBasedOnPoints(points);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following is just a refactor of your code. I haven't touched anything in the design, although I believe you should. You may start with Snyder answer.

Now, read your code and notice that you have the same code in several places in the same method. This should ring a bell, the most likely is that you copy pasted. Everytime you copy paste code, you should wait and think, because is extremely likely you will do better with that code in a separate method. That been said, this is your method:

```
private void calculateForMen(){

    // TODO Men Age 20-34
    if( strAge.equals("20 to 34") ){ // Minus 7 points

        // First point
        points = points - 9;

        // Second point
        points += Cholesterol(strTotalCholesterol, 1);                
    }
    // TODO Men Age 35-39
    else if( strAge.equals("35 to 39") ){

        // First point
        points = points - 4;

        // Second point
        points += Cholesterol(strTotalCholesterol, 1);
    }
    // TODO Men Age 40-44
    else if( strAge.equals("40 to 44") ){

        // First point
        points += 0;

        // Second point
        points += Cholesterol(strTotalCholesterol, 2);                        
    }
    // TODO Men Age 45-49
    else if( strAge.equals("45 to 49") ){

        // First point
        points += 3;

        // Second point
        points += Cholesterol(strTotalCholesterol, 2);
    }
    // TODO Men Age 50-54
    else if( strAge.equals("50 to 54") ){
        // First point
        points += 6;

        // Second point
        points += Cholesterol(strTotalCholesterol, 3);

    }
    // TODO Men Age 55-59
    else if( strAge.equals("55 to 59") ){

        // First point 
        points += 8;

        // Second point
        points += Cholesterol(strTotalCholesterol, 3);

    }
    // TODO Men Age 60-64
    else if( strAge.equals("60 to 64") ){

        // First point 
        points += 10;

        // Second point
        points += Cholesterol(strTotalCholesterol, 4);                 
    }
    // TODO Men Age 65-69
    else if( strAge.equals("65 to 69") ){

        // First point
        points += 11;

        // Second point
        points += Cholesterol(strTotalCholesterol, 4);

    }
    // TODO Men Age 70-74
    else if( strAge.equals("70 to 74") ){

        // First point
        points += 12;

        // Second point
        points += Cholesterol(strTotalCholesterol, 5);    

    }
    // TODO Men Age 75-79
    else if( strAge.equals("75 to 79") ){

        // First point
        points += 13;

        // Second point
        points += Cholesterol(strTotalCholesterol, 5);            
    }

    // Third point
    points += HDL(strHDL);
    // Fourth point
    points += SBP(strSBP);
    // Fifth point
    points += Smoker(strSmoker);

    totalPoints = points;
    strTotalPoints = String.valueOf(totalPoints);
    DisplayMaleAlert(points); 
}
```

The auxiliary methods are as follows:

```
private void DisplayMaleAlert(int points)
{
if(totalPoints < 0){
    displayMaleAlertLessThanOne();
}
else if(totalPoints >= 0 && totalPoints <= 4){
    displayMaleAlertOnePercent();
}
else if(totalPoints >= 5 && totalPoints <= 6){
    displayMaleAlertTwoPercent();
}
else if(totalPoints == 7){
    displayMaleAlertThreePercent();
}
else if(totalPoints == 8){
    displayMaleAlertFourPercent();
}
else if(totalPoints == 9){
    displayMaleAlertFivePercent();
}
else if(totalPoints == 10){
    displayMaleAlertSixPercent();
}
else if(totalPoints == 11){
    displayMaleAlertEightPercent();
}
else if(totalPoints == 12){
    displayMaleAlertTenPercent();
}
else if(totalPoints == 13){
    displayMaleAlertTwelvePercent();
}
else if(totalPoints == 14){
    displayMaleAlertSixteenPercent();
}
else if(totalPoints == 15){
    displayMaleAlertTwentyPercent();
}
else if(totalPoints == 16){
    displayMaleAlertTwentyFivePercent();
}
else if(totalPoints >= 17){
    displayMaleAlertThirtyPercent();
}
}

 private int Cholesterol(string strTotalCholesterol, int ageGroup)
 {
if(ageGroup == 1)
    return Cholesterol1(strTotalCholesterol);
if(ageGroup == 2)
    return Cholesterol1(strTotalCholesterol);
if(ageGroup == 3)
    return Cholesterol1(strTotalCholesterol);
if(ageGroup == 4)
    return Cholesterol1(strTotalCholesterol);
if(ageGroup == 5)
    return Cholesterol1(strTotalCholesterol);
 }

 private int Cholesterol1(string strTotalCholesterol)
 {
if( strTotalCholesterol.equals("160 to 199") ){// 4 points
    points = points + 4;
}
else if( strTotalCholesterol.equals("200 to 239") ){ // 8 points
    points = points + 7;
}
else if( strTotalCholesterol.equals("240 to 279") ){ // 11 points
    points += 9;
}
else if( strTotalCholesterol.equals("280 or greater") ){ // 13 points
    points += 11;
}
 }

 private int Cholesterol2(string strTotalCholesterol)
 {
if( strTotalCholesterol.equals("160 to 199") ){ // 3 points
    points += 3;
}
else if( strTotalCholesterol.equals("200 to 239")){ // 6 points
    points += 5;
}
else if( strTotalCholesterol.equals("240 to 279")){ // 8 points
    points += 6;
}
else if( strTotalCholesterol.equals("280 or greater") ){ // 10 points
    points += 8;
}
 }

private int Cholesterol3(string strTotalCholesterol)
{
if( strTotalCholesterol.equals("160 to 199") ){ // 2 points
    points += 2;
}
else if( strTotalCholesterol.equals("200 to 239")){ // 4 points
    points += 3;
}
else if( strTotalCholesterol.equals("240 to 279")){ // 5 points
    points += 4;
}
else if( strTotalCholesterol.equals("280 or greater") ){ // 7 points
    points += 5;
}    
 }

private int Cholesterol4(string strTotalCholesterol)
{
if( strTotalCholesterol.equals("160 to 199") ){ // 1 points
    points += 1;
}
else if( strTotalCholesterol.equals("200 to 239")){ // 2 points
    points += 1;
}
else if( strTotalCholesterol.equals("240 to 279")){ // 3 points
    points += 2;
}
else if( strTotalCholesterol.equals("280 or greater") ){ // 4 points
    points += 3;
}
}
private int Cholesterol5(string strTotalCholesterol)
{
if( strTotalCholesterol.equals("240 to 279")){ // 2 points
    points += 1;
}
else if( strTotalCholesterol.equals("280 or greater") ){ // 2 points
    points += 1;
}
}

private int HDL(string strHDL)
{
if( strHDL.equals("60 or greater") ) // Minus 1 point
{
    points -= 1;
}
else if( strHDL.equals("40 to 49") ){ // 1 point
    points += 1;
}
else if( strHDL.equals("Less than 40") ){ // 2 points
    points += 2;
}

}

private int SBP(string strSBP)
{
if( strSBP.equals("130 to 139")  ){ // 2 points
    points += 1;
}
else if( strSBP.equals("140 to 159")  ){ // 3 points
    points += 1;
}
else if( strSBP.equals("160 or greater")  ){ // 4 points
    points += 2;
}
}

private int Smoker(string strSmoker)
{
if(strIsSmoker.equals("Yes")){
    points += 1;                                                                                    
}
}
```